# Is there any way to create a GUI application in C without any operating system?

Tags: c, operating-system, gtk

I'm developing a mini operating system for my PC and was wondring is it possible to create a mini operating system in C that uses GUI and if it's possible to compile it using grub? I dont know what libary's i should use or if it's even possible.

I tryed this code generated from ChatGPT but it didnt let me compile it.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "GUI Bootloader");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);

  GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new("Welcome to the bootloader!");
  GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Boot");

  GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), label, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

I tryed to install the libary GTK but didnt work.

Comment: *compile it using grub* - `grub` is not a compiler... *I dont know what libary's i should use or if it's even possible.* - sure it is possible. Any modern OS is written without any other OS, and it has GUI.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to create a GUI application in C without any operating system?

No. The software that makes complicated hardware work is called an operating system. You must either use an existing operating system or provide your own.

For very simple hardware, you can write software that does dedicated tasks, and we might not call such software an operating system. However, for software that runs on a typical general-purpose computer and that manages the disk drives, the display, the keyboard, and so on, we are going to call that software, or at least part of it, the operating system. There must be some software that manages interrupts, manages data sent to and from the devices, and so on.